# Using PHP fwrite() on a high volume page

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I am currently using

```
$fp = fopen('chartdata.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($resultsarray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
fclose($fp);
```

to write my dataset to a file in JSON and then afterwards have a Google Chart read the file like so:

getjson.php

```
$string = file_get_contents("chartdata.json");
echo $string;
```

chart.php

```
function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "getjson.php",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
```

If this page were to be be high volume say 100k hits during an hour, would using this method become unsuitable? And if so what would a better method be?

Comment: Writing is not much pain like reading is. How are you reading file content? How much data does it contain?

Comment: Hi revo, I've edited my question